# leaked object in instruments even when running HelloWorld_IPhone monotouch

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, instruments

My application permanently receives memory warnings and I really cannot find what is causing it. I was getting a major leak even if I was stripping the app to the bare minimum. So what I thought was to compile the default HelloWorld_IPhone app from the monotouch examples and see whether I get the same leak. It turns out I do. Really confusing me.

[image]

The leak appears just after the app launches (red bar is filling the whole column).

> leaked object: Malloc 16 Bytes, Responsible Library: HelloWorld_IPhone, responsible frame: mono_dl_open

My question is whether this is normal or whether I am missing something?

**EDIT**:
Screenshot of Instruments output when running TweetStation app on my device in debug mode! Same results as my app. Surely something not right here? [Screenshot of Instruments output when running TweetStation app on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj9tj.png)

Comment: Seeing anything else not included in your question ? because **16 bytes** is not a *major* leak (unless it repeat itself every few seconds ?!?).

Comment: this is the output when I run my app: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/screenshot20120208at191.png/

Comment: Have you got any solution for the same @kos

Answer (score 4):

When trying to debug leaks in unmanaged code with Instruments, what you can do is create an "Allocation" instrument and then make sure that you select the option "Only Track Active Allocations", like this:

[image: Instruments Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [tirania.org](http://tirania.org/s/991d39b7.png))</sub>

This only shows the objects that are currently "live" and have not been released.   With Mono, you will notice that some objects are kept around until the garbage collector runs.    So over time the spikes of allocated objects disappear.

Comment: thanks Miguel. Oddly enough, since I couldn't make sense with why I receive so many memory warning (in Debug mode on iPod Touch) when I run my app on the iPod Touch, I thought upload the TweetStation app (Debug mode again) instead as I was curious to see the results. To my surprise, the output was very similar in that a lot of memory warning were thrown and eventually it crashed! (see image attached to original question) Has it maybe nothing to do with my app whereas more to do with something completely different? Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing a few different things. Profiling tools tends to shows a lot of data and it's easy to get lost inside all of it.

First the image you linked (I added it to your original question) is showing two things:

1. The **Allocations**. That's the Instrument's row you have selected. What it shows is what your application has allocated. You can see a **lot** of 16 bytes **allocations** but they are **not** leaks just because they are shown there.
2. An alert that shows your application has received a **Low Memory Warning**. IOW you exhausted the (device/simulator) memory and you're being notified to free up memory (or iOS will kill your application). Again it does not mean there are any (or major) leak(s).

What's not shown in your picture is what's on Instrument's second row (the **Leaks**). There **could** be a lot of leaks (but I doubt that for the hello world sample) or only a few.

There are somes cases, inside Mono (e.g. `mono_dl_open`), where memory is allocated and never freed (because it cannot be, e.g. it would close a required library). This is not *generally* an issue since the mono runtime can't be unloaded without unloading (i.e. closing) your application (where the memory will all be reclaimed by the operating system).

Anyhow we'll need more details in order to know if this leak (or others) are related with your application memory allocations (or not). If you can either supply them (edit your question here) or attach a sample to a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: the screenshot is actually from my app running on the device, and not the HelloWorld_IPhone. The problem still persists in that my app receives several warning until it crashes. The commenter was right - only one leak is showing, i.e. the one I described above. I am really stuck and cannot figure out how to best debug my app to find the high memory activity. I guess it might help to explain some more details about the app. Basically the app consumes a custom web service to find similar cases and stores these in the `Documents` folder as XML documents. see next comment for more....

Comment: In addition, the app supports audio recording and playback of generated audio ideas, that are also stored in the `Documents` folder as `wav` files. However, I cannot see why these could cause the problem, especially cause I tried to run the app without any data stored and the problem persists. Any ideas where to start? Really appreciate any help. (By the way, system does not allow me to edit original question due to the image and my low reputation...)

Comment: It seems you're retaining too much data in memory. Sadly I can't be more precise without seeing the application. You might want to try the MonoTouch profiler, from MonoDevelop, to see from where the memory is being retained. http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/MONOTOUCH_PROFILER

Comment: ok, so when I run the MonoTouch profiler I get total memory of 1,400,000 bytes (only on simulator as profiler not working on device) but when I run Activity Monitor on Instruments (on actual device) I get straight away 40 MB of memory for my app. Now I am not sure how this relates and whether this is normal but there is a huge difference. Is this normal?

Comment: MonoTouch profiler sees *only* managed memory. E.g. a small C# class (20 bytes) could allocate an **unmanaged** memory block of 20MB - but the profiler would only know about the former (not the later, but Instruments will give this to you). OTOH Instruments can't track the managed references between the .NET instances. This is where MT profiler shines :)